# Running animation made from frame in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have set up a RecyclerView like the following:

```java
public ExampleItem(int imageResource, int buy, String name, String bunz_Sec,
                       String cost, String owned){
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mBuy = buy;
        mName = name;
        mBunz_Sec = bunz_Sec;
        mCost = cost;
        mOwned = owned;

    }
```

In another file, I create multiple of these objects, like so:

```java
if (position == 1) {
            mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.baker2_1, R.drawable.buy, "Johnny", "Bunz/Sec: .2",
                    "Cost: "+ bunz.getBaker2Cost().setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING).toString(),"Owned: " +  (bunz.getBaker2())));
        }
```

I also have methods where I can modify them, like so:

```java
 ExampleItem sus = mExampleList.get(position);
                    bunz.setBaker1(bunz.getBaker1()+1); //change actual val
                    sus.setOwned(Integer.toString(bunz.getBaker1())); //change string
                    bunz.setMoney(bunz.getMoney().subtract(bunz.getBaker1Cost())); //change actual val
                    //change string
                    bunz.setBaker1Cost((BigDecimal.valueOf(40).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.15).pow(bunz.getBaker1())))); //change actual val
                    sus.setCost("Cost: " + (bunz.getBaker1Cost().setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING))); //change string
                    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Everything works fine, but I have an animation I have created out of frames, that worked fine when I just had a plain ImageView (no fancy RecylerViews). Now that I've transferred everything to a RecyclerView, I want to get the animations to run again, and I'm not sure how.

The code to start the animation (before RecyclerViews) was as follows:

```java
ImageView baker1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.baker1);
        baker1.setImageResource(R.drawable.baker1anim);
        AnimationDrawable baker1Anim = (AnimationDrawable)baker1.getDrawable();
        baker1Anim.start();
```

How can I start this animation as part of the RecyclerView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try instead imageSource set AnimationDrawable?

```
public ExampleItem(int imageResource, AnimationDrawable animationDrawable, int buy, String name, String bunz_Sec,
                       String cost, String owned){
mImageResource = imageResource;
...
}
```

Run animation in this case will be after add to list.

Upd.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html
I see recyclerView will not work properly for images that recycled(not on the screen).  So will need create a custom adaptor and use ItemAnimator

Comment: Of course converting from drawable to AnimationDrawable on if (position == 1) {...

Comment: Hmm I'll try it out right now and let you know if it works

Comment: Not really sure how to go about this, when I instantiate the objects, what do I plug in for the animationDrawable value?

Comment: Creating animationDrawable and animate in place where you initiate multiple object. if (position == 1) {...}

Comment: In another file where you set your drawable to Item object